# Can't get Asyncio to run 2 tasks in parallel (process a query result while waiting for the next query to finish)

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

Hi I'm trying to run tasks in an asynchronous way, but can't get it to work.
What I want to do is query a db (takes 30s) and process the result (takes 15s) while I make the next query.
My problem seems very simple to solve, but for some reason I can't get it to work.
Thank you very much for your help.

Here is my code so far

```
async def query_db(date):
    sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date='{date}'"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine)
    df.to_csv(f"{date}_data.csv", index=False)

async def process_df(filepath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    # Do processing stuff here and save the modified file

for dte in pd.date_range("2020-10-10", "2020-10-12", freq='D'):
    query_data_task = asyncio.create_task(query_db(dte))
    filepath = f"{dte}_data.csv"
    await query_data_task
    process_dataframe = asyncio.create_task(process_df(filepath))
```

Comment: Your query and process functions don’t await anything. `await` is needed to return control back to the event loop so that something else can run. Either you need an asyncio-aware database driver so that querying can be awaited, or you’ll need an executor. As an I/O-bound task, querying is better for threads. As a CPU-bound task, processing is better for processes. If your times are accurate, or at least representative, you can probably get a bit boost from awaiting the query and just letting the processing run synchronously.